# Get a relative URL of the uploaded file attachment in Laravel orchid?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Hello I am adding the functionality to upload files to the server using the laravel orchid. I am sending the (partial) URL to the file stored on the hard-drive back to the frontend.
I am retrieving the file URL using the $attachment->url() that gives a full URL string but I would like to know how to get a relative URL to the file.

The code I have looks similar to

```
public function uploadPhoto(Request $request)
{
    $file = new File($request->file('fileData'));
    $attachment = $file->load();

    error_log("Uploaded url". $attachment->url());

    return response()->json();
}
```

This outputs:

http://localhost/storage/2022/06/08/247437ba9e73954388a4a350fc0f292409a679d4.jpg

But I want to get a relative URL:

/storage/2022/06/08/247437ba9e73954388a4a350fc0f292409a679d4.jpg

How can I get a relative URL to the uploaded file from the attachment in Laravel orchid?

Comment: Did you already move the uploaded file to the storage folder by move method? Because by default, my file inputs are being temporarily stored in the temp folders. Like:

"D:\xampp\tmp\php36F6.tmp"

Anyway, if you did move the attachment already, then it should be easy to simply prepend the url you set for it when using the move method.

Comment: @Mash tan, I had no issues with the storage so far. The filess uploaded are stored in the public/storage/yyyy-mm-dd/filehash. You should check the app/config/filesystems.php to set the default location of the drive, on my side it is the 'root' => storage_path('app/public'). For the question on hand, I need the relative URLs because the domain of the site is temporary. I can retrieve the relative urls with the $relativeUrl = parse_url($attachment->url(), PHP_URL_PATH) method  but I am wondering if there is a more correct approach of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the url relative to the public folder use

```
$attachment->relativeUrl
```

or

```
parse_url($attachment->url(), PHP_URL_PATH)
```

Note that `$attachment->url()` additionally does an extra check to confirm that the file exists on the hard drive.

> The url() method will first check for the path existence, and then get
> the URL. When using external storage like s3, this will make two
> calls. To improve performance you can use the caching adapter
> recommended by Laravel to improve performance. You can also simply
> override this method and adjust to your needs.
> [Orchid Attachments](https://orchid.software/en/docs/attachments/#uploading-a-file-via-the-http)